# Algorithm for minimizing pixel stretching effect 

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am looking algorithms or techniques so that i can minimize the pixel stretching effect for a given image. I am not looking for any tool.

Comment: What are you doing with the image, other than displaying it?

Comment: By "minimize the pixel stretching effect" I assume you mean [pixelation](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/pixelated.html).

Comment: So you mean pixel stretching when you resize the image?

Comment: actually i have set of images which i play to display it as a video. The aspect ratio is 1.22: 1. because of this there is stretching effect. my job is to minimize this.i have image in RGB format

Answer (score 2):

I heard about this cool new place called Wikipedia that might have some info on what you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering

Comment: Sure steal my thunder as I try to recall if the term is pixelation or pixelization. :-) Good reference articles tho!

Answer (score 0):

Rob Stephens' book [Visual Basic Graphics Programming](http://www.vb-helper.com/vbgp.htm) probably has the algorithm you are looking for.